# Why does $ObjectType.Sobject.fields.FieldName.Label render different Label

Tags: apex, visualforce

I have the following markup on a Visualforce Page:

```
<apex:pageBlockSection title="Account" columns="1">
    <apex:inputField value="{!CurrentOrder.AccountId}"/>
</apex:pageBlockSection>
```

Also:

```
<apex:outputLabel value="{!$ObjectType.Order.fields.AccountId.Label}"/>
<apex:inputField value="{!CurrentOrder.AccountId}"/>
```

The First markup renders the label as "Account Name".

The Second markup renders the label as "Account Id"

I don't understand why the 2 would be different. I'm using the same Object and Field.
Can someone clarify?

Answer (score 6):

It's a little esoteric, I think.  You are asking VF to create an input field for an ID, which can't be changed.  So it is converting it to a name, which can be used properly in an input field.  I might have to double check that, but it fits in line with how most VF components work.  Otherwise you get a bound field which if the user updates will return a controller error.

The labels are different because in the first case VF has done the translation I describe above, but in the second case you are creating a distinct output label pointing to the entry in the describe field (so it is unaware such a translation is going to take place)

Comment: Shouldn't the inputField markup that is bound to Order.AccountId get it's label from the same place that $ObjectType.Order.fields.AccountId.Label comes from? They both reference the Order.AccountId field. I've also seen this happen on Opportunity.AccountId. This also happens on Order.BillToContactId. If I'm asking for a Label, I should get the same value whether it's bound using inputField or through the $ObjectType.Order.fields.AccountId.Label which it looks like is using describe to get values.

Comment: Yeah sorry, my answer was a little incomplete.  Updated.

Comment: Is there a way to get to the translated "Account Name" label value without using the inputField markup? Also If I override the Label in "Rename Tabs and Labels" for Bill To Contact, both mark up ways will render the overridden value.

Comment: For added fun - if your org has currencies enabled - compare the label of the picklist **and** the picklist options on regular page and on VF page ;)